# Connect to localhost POP3 server through Thunderbird\Outlook

Tags: java, server, pop3

Trying to connect to my own POP3 server on localhost(1024 port). Its code:

```
 server_socket = new ServerSocket(SBAP_PORT);
 Socket clntSocket = server_socket.accept();
 public void run() {
    try {
        try {
            in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()
                    ));
            out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            out.print("+OK\\r\\n");
            command = in.readLine();
            String result = handleInput(command);
            out.println(result);
        } finally {
            socket.close();
            state.close();
            System.out.println("client offline.");
        }
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
    }
}
```

It's working fine with telnet, but when I try to do it with Thunderbird, just get timeout(Failed to find settings for your email account).

In debug I see, that I get null string while connecting.

What am I doing wrong? Maybe I should send something to client just after connecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it must be `\r\n` rather `\\r\\n`, plus try to flush for each response you send to the client by `out.flush();`, but it might not be necessary.

Comment: It doesn't work neither with out.print("+OK\\r\\n") nor with it. 
Server just sending me null strings. I can't find out, if he want's something from me to send before actual Command receiving...

Comment: no dear you should change `out.print("+OK\\r\\n");` to `out.print("+OK\r\n");`, please have another try @Xerocry